# Using Select-Object on two adjacent lines in a row outputs a "broken" list

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Consider the following example:

```
if ([Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") -eq $null) {return}
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server servername
$server | Select Name, Product, Edition, VersionString 
$server.Databases | select name,CompatibilityLevel
```

If executed line per line on the command line, the output will somewhat resemble the following:

```
Name                                     Product                                  Edition                                 VersionString                          
----                                     -------                                  -------                                 -------------                          
SERVERNAME                               Microsoft SQL Server                     Developer Edition (64-bit)              12.0.4213.0                            

Name                                                                     CompatibilityLevel
----                                                                     ------------------
Database123456789                                                                Version100
Database234567890                                                                Version100
```

If executed as a script, the output looks like the following (note the missing "Version100"...):

```
Name                                     Product                                  Edition                                 VersionString                          
----                                     -------                                  -------                                 -------------                          
SERVERNAME                               Microsoft SQL Server                     Developer Edition (64-bit)              12.0.4213.0                            
Database123456789                                                                                                                                                
Database234567890
```

Even changing the script like this won't help with the output being messed up.

```
if ([Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") -eq $null) {return}
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server servername
$server | Select Name, Product, Edition, VersionString 
Write-Host "Databases on $($server.Name):"
$server.Databases | select name,CompatibilityLevel
```

Instead the output will look like this:

```
Name                                     Product                                  Edition                                 VersionString                          
----                                     -------                                  -------                                 -------------                          
SERVERNAME                               Microsoft SQL Server                     Developer Edition (64-bit)              12.0.4213.0                            
Databases on SERVERNAME:
Database123456789                                                                                                                                                
Database234567890
```

How can I force PowerShell to output the CompatibilityLevel member?

Comment: You're outputting multiple kinds of objects, and the default output formatter isn't consolidating the disparate objects. I am wondering what you are expecting the output to look like, exactly?

Comment: I want the output to look like when I execute the script line per line. However, piping the second Select-Object through Format-List like mentioned in jisaak's answer below indeed achieves the desired result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Format-Table](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113303) cmdlet to force the output:

```
$server.Databases | select name,CompatibilityLevel | Format-Table
```